# Python Image Processing leaves segmentation

Tags: python

I need to make a college project for my class of Digital image processing, and one part is segment a image with many leaves and write which one in another image file. I get a decent result but for a image with 6000x4000 pixels the code run too slow (5-10 minutes per leave). Can I improve this code?

The code for get next leave:

```
for i in range(0, height):
 for j in range(0, width):
  if not np.all(image[i, j] == white):
     ....
```

The code for get all pixels of the leave (k neighbors):

```
def percorreVizinhos(image, vizinhos, lin, col): 
  image[lin][col] = white

  fila = [[lin, col]]

  while fila:
    lin, col = fila.pop()
    vizinhosList = [[lin-1, col], [lin, col-1], [lin, col+1], [lin+1, col]]

    for vizinho in vizinhosList:
      line_v, col_v = vizinho

      if(line_v > 0 and line_v < height and col_v > 0 and col_v < width):
        cor = image[line_v][col_v]

        if not np.all(cor == white):
          image[line_v][col_v] = white
          vizinhos.append(vizinho)
          fila.append(vizinho)

  return vizinhos
```

Link to the input and output image example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdZz1.jpg

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: There are some useful topics for that like parallelism (multithreading) . Try using pthread Library for python.